# Apollonian gaskets - algorithm

Tags: java, fractals

The task is definitely described there [Recursively create apollonian gaskets [With solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118029/recursively-create-apollonian-gaskets)

But I tried to find the radius of all the circles. So, I used [Descartes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem)  for it. You can find radius using the curvatures.

But there is error in algorithm, because the output differs from the check data.

How do you think, where is it?

Formule of finding the curvatures of the new circle.

```
public static double next(double a,double b, double c){
    return (a+b+c+2*Math.sqrt(a*b+b*c+c*a));
}
```

The code of finding all the curvatures.

`Radius = 1/curvature`.

`Su` = sum of areas of all circles in the gasket except for the bigggest circle.

`Ar` = sum of perimeters of all circles in the gasket except for the bigggest circle.

```
public static void newCircle(double a,double b, double c){
    double k=next(a,b,c);
    Su=(float) (Su+2*(2*Math.PI*(1/k)));
    Ar=(float) (Ar+2*(Math.PI*((1/k)*(1/k))));
    if(2*(1/k)>minD){
        newCircle(a,c,k);
    }
}
```

I suggest, there must be somthing, that would make my algorithm truly. For example, output should be `'2439.258588 835.263228'`, but it is `'2161.9133 499.28397'`.
But I can`t find, what is incorrect.
Maybe, new circles should be found in another way, I think, that one circle gives 2 new(that have the same radius). First 2 circles and one Big gives 2 circles, than one Big, one of the first and new circle give 2...
So

```
'newCircle(k1,k2,next);
   newCircle(k1,k3,next);'
```

`'k1'`-Big
`'k2,k3'` - first ones

Well, now there is good solving [Recursively create apollonian gaskets [With solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118029/recursively-create-apollonian-gaskets-solved)

Comment: What do you mean by error in you algorithm? What happens that shouldn't?

Comment: I suggest, there must be somthing, that would make my algorithm truly. For example, output should be '2439.258588 835.263228', but it is '2161.9133 499.28397'.
But I can`t find, what is incorrect.